# Get autoincrement id after an insert query performed

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

I want to get the autoincrement id of an insert.

is there a way to do it?

Comment: In what language?  Are you using a Sproc to do the inserting?

Answer (score 7):

Seeing as you're specifying only mySQL in your tags:

Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Make sure to read the manual page for the subtleties.

The language you are querying mySQL from may have built-in API functions that do the same thing.

Comment: Damn, Pekka, do you ever sleep? ;-)

Comment: If I put ISERT INTO TB_EX etc..; LAST_INSERT_ID(); if I insert another element before calling LAST_INSERT_ID() wont return the wrong result? For example in a multi-thread environment?

Comment: @okami it might return the wrong result. See the manual page: `returns the first automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT statement to affect such a column`. Whether it's multi-threaded or not doesn't matter though, it's always per connection

Comment: @Pekka: thanks for this last addition: 'always per connection'. That's something I didn't know and can solve my problem, as mentioned by Okami: a lot of inserts on almost the same time by diffent modules..... therefor my upvote!